# $AQ \cap BM = X$ and $BN \cap AP = Y$. Prove that $AB, MP, NQ$ and $XY$ are concurrent.

Tags: geometry

> $E$ and $F$ are points lying on the semicircle $(O, AB)$, $(OEF) \cap AB = D \not\equiv O$. $AF$ intersects $(BDE)$ at $M$ and $N$ $(AM < AF)$. $BE$ intesects $(ADF)$ at $P$ and $Q$ $(BN < BE)$. $AQ \cap BM = X$ and $BN \cap AP = Y$. Prove that $AB, MP, NQ$ and $XY$ are concurrent.

[image]

It can be noticed that $AN, BQ$ and $XY$ are concurrent.

However, $(ABXY), (XYNQ), (ABNQ) \ne -1$ so I am currently blind on what to do at the moment.

Comment: why don't you post these kinds of questions on AOPS?

Comment: That's a question that I have yet known how to answer. Simply, I don't know.

Comment: Do you mean "E and F" instead of "M and N" in the sentence, "M and N are points lying on the semicircle (O,AB)"? That confusion incited strong resistance in my mind to follow through with the problem.